# Import content using the "Default Content for D8" module

Tags: 8, nodes, installation-profiles

I am using [Default Content for D8](https://www.drupal.org/project/default_content) to import content on my site.

After Profile installation completed, I enabled my custom default content module with contents sample json for node entity [my_module/content/[entity_type]/anything.json].

I get the following error:

> Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\UnexpectedValueException: Type
>   /drupal-pro-8/rest/type/node/article does not
>   correspond to an entity on this site. in
>   Drupal\hal\Normalizer\ContentEntityNormalizer->getTypedDataIds() (line
>   239 of
>   \drupal-pro-8\core\modules\hal\src\Normalizer\ContentEntityNormalizer.php).

And the node isn't imported...

What have I done to try to fix it:

. Ensure I have the article content type;

. Flushed all cache;

. Tested in different browsers;

. In the module page it says all tests were passed with the following conditions: PHP 5.5 & MySQL 5.5, D8.5 6. I started to use the same version of PHP, MySQL and D8.

After all this, the same problem keeps on appearing and I can't understand why this happens. May I missed something. Any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know how import data from .csv into drupal 8. Does that help you?

Comment: did you flush all caches?

Comment: @brotherperes - No, I need to use Default Content for D8 module. Yes, I cleared but it is not working.

Comment: What's your php, mysql and drupal versions?

Comment: @brotherperes - PHP version: 7.1.9, Mysql -  4.7.5, drupal 8.3

Comment: The module passed the test under the following conditions: PHP 5.5 & MySQL 5.5, D8.5 6. Can you have them the same and test if your problem persists?

Comment: @brotherperes - Sure, I will try. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Keep me posted, I want to help

Comment: sure, meanwhile this is my profile repository, If you want to debug more https://github.com/latikavs/drupal-profile-8

Comment: @brotherperes - After installed with the same version still I am getting the same error. "Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\UnexpectedValueException: Type http://localhost:8080/drupal-pro-8/rest/type/node/article does not correspond to an entity on this site. in Drupal\hal\Normalizer\ContentEntityNormalizer->getTypedDataIds() (line 239 of /var/www/public/core/modules/hal/src/Normalizer/ContentEntityNormalizer.php)."

Comment: @brotherperes - Did you get time to look into this issue? I resolved this error but data not imported. I really thankful, if you provide some brief document to import the content using this module.

Comment: Are you using module version 8.x-1.0-alpha7? They say this one passed all tests...

Comment: @brotherperes - Yes, I am using the same.

Comment: I can see content type 'article' is already there (thought this would be the problem). Can you test in a different browser?

Comment: @brotherperes - I checked with different browsers, but did not work.

Answer (score 1):

This will be probably resolved by setting the _links type href domain as `http://drupal.org` (the default links domain used by default_content module) in yor .json files to import, instead of `drupal-pro-8` that was set form the site you exported?.